# append new nodes and attributes in xml file using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have xml file format like this

```
<project>
  <node name="abc" description="abc-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
  <node name="def" description="def-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
 
</project>
```

now after appending new node name it should look like this

```
<project>
  <node name="abc" description="abc-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
  <node name="def" description="def-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
  <node name="xyz" description="xyz-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
 
</project>
```

but when I append using xml commands it is adding as shown in below format. Its not closing the subnode.

```
    <project>
  <node name="abc" description="abc-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
  <node name="def" description="def-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu">
  </node>
  <node name="xyz" description="xyz-describe" tags="test-tag"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu" />
   
</project>
```

here is the command which i used.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -s "/project" -t elem -n node -i "//node[3]"  -t attr -n "name" -v "xyz" -i  "//node[3]" -t attr -n "description" -v "xyz-describe" -i  "//node[3]" -t attr -n "tags" -v "test-tag" -i "//node[3]" -t attr -n "osFamily" -v "unix" -i  "//node[3]" -t attr -n "osName" -v "Ubuntu" file.xml
```

can someone help me on this?

Comment: You have an error, missing closing square bracket on `"xyz-describe" -i  "//node[3"`

Comment: What is the `xmlstarlet --version` ? Works well with `1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.10, linked with 20913
compiled against libxslt 1.1.34, linked with 10134`

Comment: yes, I missed closing square bracket here but I ran it correctly. My version also same as you mentioned

Comment: Which OS do you run ?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an empty text node (or one containing a newline and
indentation):

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  -s '/project' -t elem -n node \
  --var nd '$prev' \
  -s '$nd' -t text -n 'ignored' -v '' \
  -s '$nd' -t attr -n 'name' -v 'xyz' \
  … \
file.xml
```

- `--var` defines a named variable, and the `$prev` variable refers
  to the node(s) created by the most recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option
  which all define or redefine it (see
  [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
  for examples of `--var` and `$prev`)
- `…` is where the remaining attributes belong

Comment: its giving same output. Its not closing the node loop

Comment: @Vanaan: At my end `xmlstarlet` 1.6.1 produces the desired output, with or without the `-L` option. What output do you get from `xmlstarlet --version`?

Comment: I got this output 
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.10, linked with 20913
compiled against libxslt 1.1.34, linked with 10134

Comment: @Vanaan: In that case I don't think you're following my suggestion: 
`echo '<p/>' | xmlstarlet edit -O -P -s '/p' -t elem -n n` outputs `<p><n/></p>`, 
and `echo '<p/>' | xmlstarlet edit -O -P -s '/p' -t elem -n n  -s '$prev' -t text -n na -v ''` outputs `<p><n></n></p>`.
Semantically, `<node name="xyz"></node>` and `<node name="xyz"/>` are identical, but they're serialized differently.

Comment: @Vanaan: If you're using double quotes around `$prev` change them to single quotes, or the shell will prevent `xmlstarlet` from seeing that `$prev` variable (also known as `$xstar:prev`).

Comment: thaks you. `xmlstarlet edit -O -P -s '/p' -t elem -n n  -s '$prev' -t text -n na -v ''` this is working

Comment: this also worked for me...
`xmlstarlet edit  -s '/project' -t elem -n node -s '//node' -t text -n 'ignored' -v ''  -s '//node' -t attr -n 'name' -v 'xyz'   …       file.xml`